# How to create and run docker container with new user other than root?

Tags: docker

I met a problem while using docker.
Now I have a ubuntu based docker container. And in the container ,the user id is root by default which is not my expectation, I suppose the user id is like `abc` which is another user account on the HOST OS running docker.
I have tried the following ways but all fail:

```
su abc;
```

Then running `docker run xxx` to bring up a container, but login the container, the user in container is still `root`.

Then by adding the `-u` flag for docker run: like :

```
docker run -t -i -u abc ubuntu /bin/bash
```

the the docker show errors `unable to find user abc`

Can some one tell me how to fix it?

Or does docker support run a container in which the user is a specific one than the default `root`?

Comment: You can run as a user other than root but you need to create the user in the image (using Dockerfile) first. Also if you have a `USER` line in the Dockerfile, that user becomes the default user when you login.

Answer (score 1):

You can create User inside Docker images. But for that you will have to extend base image. For example you can create user `abc` in Ubuntu as below,

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update

# Replace 1000 with your user / group id
RUN export uid=1000 gid=1000 && \
    mkdir -p /home/abc && \
    echo "abc:x:${uid}:${gid}:Abc,,,:/home/abc:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd && \
    echo "abc:x:${uid}:" >> /etc/group && \
    echo "abc ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/abc && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/abc && \
    chown ${uid}:${gid} -R /home/abc

USER abc
ENV HOME /home/abc
WORKDIR $HOME
CMD /bin/bash
```

Then you build and run it,

```
docker build -t abc .
docker run -it abc bash
```

you should see bash prompt with user `abc` like below,

```
abc@<container-hostname>:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15, this is possibly, but you can only refer to HOST users by their numerical ids.  Read that helpful article for more details and a fuller explanation.